# Redirect 301 Apache to new site - Folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wan't to redirect

```
www.site123.com/images/folder01/img01.jpg
```

to

```
www.site456.com/images/folder02/img01.jpg
```

I want to redirect the folder to folder separately. One line for each folder.

Entering in:

```
www.site123.com/images/folder01/sub01/sub02/999.xyz
```

Should be redirected (301) to:

```
www.site456.com/images/folder01/sub01/sub02/999.xyz
```

Comment: I appears you did not get the idea of this forum. This forum is not to make your homework for you. You will have to do them yourself. In this forum you get help when you tried it yourself and have a specific question or problem. So take the documentation of the redirection module, google for a few examples and learn by solving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the directory structure from site123 to site456 look identical, have you tried the following global redirect?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site456.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

If directory/specific then change your rule to something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*) http://www.site456.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want sub-folders too:

```
RewriteRule ^Images/?(.*) http://www.site456.com/Images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Create a line for each pattern you wish to match and change the corresponding redirect URL/folder path.  With rewrites it's sometimes trial/error too so take this and try it, then tweak as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately not all the site's structure is identical, so I want to do folder by folder separately.

Always starting with this folder:
`/images/folderXXXXX`

Comment: Off to bed now but that should give you some options to try.  Every use case is different so it's trial/error but those options will help you narrow down.